# Expectations in Infinite Probability Spaces with Sub Sigma-Algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, expected-value

The ideas that need to be proven all make sense to me intuitively, but I just don't know how to go about formalizing the actual proof itself in an infinite probability space. I tried approaching it from a finite probability space standpoint, but I don't think it's working.

Comment: What do you know about the various definitions? For example, in order to answer (a), you need to compute $\mathbb{E}(Z)$ and show it is equal to $\mathbb{E}(X)$. The former is by definition $\int_\Omega \mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G}) d\mathbb{P}$. Can you use the definition of the conditional expectation to evaluate it?

Comment: Can I just say something along the lines of $\mathbb{E}(X-Z)=\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}(X))=\mathbb{E}(X)-\mathbb{E}(X)=0$ ? Any chance you have any pointers for the following parts? I'm having some trouble determining what I am allowed to / not allowed to do in an infinite probability space that I might have been able to do in a finite probability space.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ are very different things! The former is a number. The latter is a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function. You need to review your course notes to understand this difference.

Comment: I thought this was a property when $X$ is $G$-Measurable?

Comment: Where in your question did you see that $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable? Your $X$ is only initially assumed to be $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Also, when $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable, the property is that $E(X|\mathcal{G}) = X$, not $E(X|\mathcal{G}) = E(X)$.

Comment: Understood - I'll spend some time working that out, but how do I use that to move to the next part of the question? (Sorry this is my first time working in infinite probability spaces..)

Comment: For part (b), first try to prove that the integral of $X - Z$ over any set $G\in \mathcal{G}$ is equal to zero. Then approximate $(Z-Y)$ (since it is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable) by simple functions (relative to the sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$). Parts (c) and (d) are just tiny algebraic manipulations after this.